# lightm fail to start LXDE,but LXDE works with startx

Tags: server, lightdm, lxde

I installed lxde on **ubuntu server 16.04.3**.every thing was fine untill i purged lxde and re-installed it.now i can start lxde with `startx`,but not with using lightdm or `startlxde`.

In lightdm it says **failed to start session**

I tried moving ~/.Xauthority and re installing LXDE.no result,i couldn't find any answer on internet so please don't duplicate my question.

Any help would be appereciated.

**EDIT:**
when i install ubuntu-deskop,the problem is fixed and i can login to LXDE.but when i purge ubuntu-desktop,the problem is back again.

**EDIT2:**
I've also purged,removed all packages that where leftover,autoremoved,autocleaned then install LXDE again,but no luck.

Comment: why not purge all and run autoremove, autoclean and reinstall? sometimes it may work

Comment: i've also tested it.i've purged it,removed all packages that where leftover,autoremoved all,autocleaned all and installed again.

Comment: Verify that you have `lightdm-gtk-greeter` installed. Otherwise, the screen will freeze on login for some LightDM versions.

Comment: @GTRONICK,it doesn't freeze,it says failed to start session

Answer (score 1):

Same happened to me on a freshly installed **Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS**.
After installing LXDE via `sudo apt install lxde`.
Turned out it was not setting the default session in lightdm.conf, indeed the file was not there at all. To fix this you just need to create a file **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** (or edit it if it's already there) and write this inside:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=LXDE
```

Beware LXDE has to be written uppercase as it's .desktop file is named inside **/usr/share/xsessions/** folder.
After that simply reboot and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ubuntu 18.04 after installing `lxde`, I would get "failed to start session" when I put in the correct password. (Putting the incorrect password gave a different error.) I did `apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and this solved it.